# I want to put two landscape A5 pages (.ps or .pdf) on one portrait A4 page (.ps or .pdf)

Tags: pdf, postscript, imposition

I created a document in A5 size and managed to reshuffle the pages of the produced .pdf output with psbook, so that the pages have the perfect order for a booklet.

There are lots of hints that the next step would work with psnup, but that's not true. I also tried a2ps and pstops with various options. The last thing I found was bookletimposer (Ubuntu), but it has failed as well.

It seems so easy, because no scaling and no rotating is involved. Just put one page @ position 0,0 and the following on @ 0,14,85cm (half the height of the A4 page).

input:

```
+----------+
| this is  |
| page one |
+----------+

+----------+
| this is  |
| page two |
+----------+
```

output:

```
+----------+
| this is  |
| page one |
|          |
| this is  |
| page two |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you had a multipage pdf file, let's say consisting in 16 sequentially ordered pages:

> **1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16**

and you already reordered the pages to have this new sequence:

> **16,1,2,15,14,3,4,13,12,5,6,11,10,7,8,9**

and these pages are oriented in landscape mode

you can use, on this last file,

**Multivalent.jar** (last free version with pdf tools included)

- https://rg.to/file/c6bd7f31bf8885bcaa69b50ffab7e355

with this syntax:

```
java -cp /path/to.../Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Impose -dim 1x2  -paper A4 A5-already-huffled_for_imposing.pdf
```

since you have already the pages rightly shuffled for imposing:

> **16,1,2,15,14,3,4,13,12,5,6,11,10,7,8,9**

Multivalent will pick

pages 16,1 ...and put on same page (front 1)

[image: front]

pages 2,15 ...and put on same page (back 1)

[image: back]

and so on... achieving the goal to create a perfectly imposed booklet

Comment: **Thank you.** That works really well. What a pity that the ordinary psnup tools have no way to achieve this.